# Server sent unexpected return value (405 Not Allowed). Nginx, SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, nginx, http-status-code-405

All greetings. Installed and configured the SVN, but the project is to commit a mistake and not complete. Server nginx, client - tortoise. Gives the following error:

> Commit failed (details follow): Server
>   sent unexpected return value (405 Not
>   Allowed) in response to PUT request
>   for
>   '/repos/!svn/wrk/79c6d77f-f269-1044-bc71-05a5edf2f865/subdomain/ajax/toggleElements/js.gif'

image log: http://floomby.ru/content/meNBRRpAT0/

Seek a solution in the internet, nothing definite is said, written, which is associated with nginx and everything ubiraenie slash in the Location outcome has not

How to fix a bug? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Either your server is behind a firewall that is blocking DAV requests, Apache is setup to reject them or the file `/ajax/toggleElements/js.gif` already exists in the repository.

I would bet the last, I can't be sure but updating your working copy might fix the error.

Comment: If this firewall, why is it not block the first n-queries?

Repository on the server totally empty.

Comment: This problem occurs when you import any folder, with any set of files

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is discussed here:
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,2414

However does not seem to be a solution yet. i tried the workaround:

```
 error_page   405   = @405;
 location = @405 {
     root   ...;
 }
```

but then i got 500 error instead.

Comment: In the page, it says "error_page 405 =200 @405;" but you write "error_page 405 = @405;" instead. Maybe this ?